# Improving activity loading speed with layout size more then 3500 lines

Tags: android

I am making ludo game in android i use relative and liner layout to make a complete board design and user draw ables with all these things my layout size is increasing too much its approx 3500 line and my activity takes 4 to 10 second to start or load can anyone suggest me what i can do for this to improve my activity loading speed.

Comment: Try using `ConstraintLayout`, it'll remove your **nested view hierarcy**.

Comment: with ConstraintLayout its size is much more then my current code in constraintlayout we have to use more constraints and with this it is not adjust all type of screens with my current flexible UI

Comment: May be acc. to you say, Code for ConstraintLayout may be more but it'll render faster than other layouts because, it makes flat view hierarchy.

Comment: Since you need speed, the only way to juice Android performance is to create your own custom view by creating a subclass of View class. This would be a broad topic honestly.

Comment: @ Jeel Vankhede do you ever see ludo board if not please see first and think about all views lines tokens,dice and all other stuffs do you think all these will be managed as you say

Comment: I am here just to see dat layout

Answer (score 0):

One way of helping your Activity run faster is keeping the amount of work to be done in `onCreate()` to as little as possible.

Remove code from `onCreate()` that does not have to be executed during the start of the activity. This will reduce the amount of 'delay' that you are currently getting.